# Classes communicating via buffers - best practices?

Tags: c++, pointers, buffer

I started poking about this topic simply as an experiment. Suppose you have two classes. The "receiver" class has to copy a block of memory stored at a location maintained by a "sender" class to its own block of memory it maintains. For example, the sender class could model an OpenGL rendering engine which generates bitmaps depicting a particular graphical scene and those bitmaps are then passed as raw buffer data to the reciever class which could model a GUI element displaying those images in the user interface of an application.

The sender class is declared as follows:

```
class Sender {
public:
    Sender(size_t = 0);
    ~Sender();
    bool isEmpty();
    void generateRandomData();
    void exposeBuffer(unsigned char*&);
    void exposeBufferSize(size_t&);
private:
    size_t buffer_size;
    unsigned char* buffer;
};
```

While the receiver class is declared as follows:

```
class Receiver {
public:
    Receiver(size_t = 0);
    Receiver(Sender&);
    ~Receiver();
    bool isEmpty();
    void receive(Sender&);
private:
    size_t buffer_size;
    unsigned char* buffer;
};
```

The communication logic happening inside the main function:

```
int main() {
    int status(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    Sender my_sender(10);
    my_sender.generateRandomData();
    Receiver my_receiver(my_sender);
    my_receiver.receive(my_sender);
    return status;
}
```

The important methods used for communications are defined as follows

The reception is implemented as a member function of the Receiver class:

```
void Receiver::receive(Sender& sender) {
    size_t sender_buffer_size;
    sender.exposeBufferSize(sender_buffer_size);
    if (sender_buffer_size != buffer_size) {
        std::cout << "ERROR : receive : Incompatible buffer sizes!" <<
            std::endl;
        return;
    }
    unsigned char* sender_buffer = nullptr;
    sender.exposeBuffer(sender_buffer);

    std::memcpy(buffer, sender_buffer, buffer_size);
}
```

In the above code, the most critical point I am concerned about is the implementation of the exposeBuffer member function of Sender:

```
void Sender::exposeBuffer(unsigned char* &to) {
    to = buffer;
}
```

My main concerns are:

1. Is this implementation of communicating raw buffer data safe and considered a good practice?
2. Can I do better than to expose the Sender buffer by copying its location to a pointer passed by reference (Sender::exposeBuffer)
3. Did I overlook a standard way of doing this, which I can read about somewhere?

Comment: wouldn't you want to transfer a handle to the buffer in the GPU, and never transfer the actual data across the bus?

Comment: @RichardHodges I would like the Sender class to completely isolate GPU communication from the rest of the program.

Comment: so maybe encapsulate the handle to the GPU-owned data in a class. Or am I misunderstanding? Do you need to actually inspect the bitmap in code?

Comment: @RichardHodges This started out just as a thought experiment. My only intention would be to display the image in a GUI element. Thats why I stumbled across the topic of buffer comunication.

Comment: I see. In that case you certainly want to communicate buffer handles, and leave the actual bitmaps etc in the GPU. The last thing you want to do is transfer data across the GPU bus unnecessarily.